# Show / Hide table values

Tags: javascript, json, datatables

I am using datatable.js. I list json data on tablature. The inputs will be visible and invisible according to the true and false values ​​of the list. 
For example, if tur = true, 3rd column show, 1st and 2nd column hide. 
If tur = false, the 1st and 2nd columns show should be 3rd hide. I could not run it. Could you help me?

```js
testdata = [{
    "id": "58",
    "country_code": "UK",
    "title": "",
    "pubdate": "",
    "url": "",
    "tur": true
}, {
    "id": "59",
    "country_code": "UK",
    "title": "",
    "pubdate": "",
    "url": "",
    "tur": false
}];

$('#test').dataTable({
    "aaData": testdata,
        "aoColumns": [{
        "mDataProp": "id"
    }, {
        "mDataProp": "country_code"         
    }, {
        "mDataProp": "title",
        "render": function (mDataProp, type, row,meta){
            var giris = '';

            giris = '<input class="input1" type="text" ></input>';
            return giris;

          }
    }, {
        "mDataProp": "pubdate",
        "render": function (mDataProp, type, row,meta){
            var giris = '';

            giris = '<input class="input2" type="text" ></input>';
            return giris;

          }
    }, {
        "mDataProp": "url",
        "render": function (mDataProp, type, row,meta){
            var giris = '';

            giris = '<input class="input3" type="text" ></input>';
            return giris;

          }
    },{
        "mDataProp": "tur",
        "render": function (mDataProp, type, row, meta) {
                var result = '';
                  //result = '<span class="center-block padding-5 label label-success">' + metin + '</span>';                  
                  result='<button type="button" class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> EKLE</button>'                

                  if(row.tur){ 
                    $('.input1').show();
                    $('.input2').hide();
                    $('.input3').hide();                    
                    console.log("true "+ row.id);
                  } 
                  else if(!row.tur){
                    $('.input2').show();
                    $('.input3').show();      
                    $('.input1').hide();   
                    console.log("false " + row.id);    
                  }
                  return result;

            }
    }]
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/s8JmF/837/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that when you run `$('.input2').hide();`, the script goes through all your DOM elements with class `input2` and hides them. This is why, if the last call was `.hide()`, all the inputs in the table with that class will be hidden.

There are different ways to prevent it. One way, would be to assign unique class to each input. For example:

```
//...
"render": function (mDataProp, type, row,meta){
    var giris = '';
    giris = '<input class="input2-'+row.id+'"" type="text" ></input>';
    return giris;
}
//...
// then show or hide
$('.input2-' + row.id).hide();
//...
```

Here, I added the id of the table element to the class name. Because the class name now became something like `input2-58`, it will be unique to that row only. As a result, showing or hiding it will not affect other input fields in the document.

If your `row.id` is not unique, you can use some other unique identification to append to the class name. If you need the class names for CSS, and do not want to change them, then you can add a unique `id` to the `<input>` tag or add another class. Well, you get the idea. Basically, make the DOM element selection unique, so they are not affecting other input fields.